# Cannot connect Linux XAMPP PHP to SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, xampp

I've searched many sites without success.  I'm using XAMPP 1.7.3a on Ubuntu 9.1.

I have used the methods found at http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mssql_database.php, they all fail.  I am able to "connect" with a linked database through MS Access, however, that is not an acceptable solution as not all users will have Access.

The first method (at webcheatsheet) uses mssql_connect, et.al. but I get this error from the mssql_connect() call:

**Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: *[my server]* in *[my code]***

[my server] is the server address, I have used both the host name and the IP address.
[my code] is a reference to the file and line number in my .php file.

Is there a log file somewhere that would have more information about the failure, both on my machine and SQL Server?  We do not have a bona-fide DBA, so I will need specific information to pass on if the issue seems to be on the server side.

All assistance is appreciated, including RTM when the location of the M is provided!
Thanks

Comment: given that your code is correct and the db is up and running do you have selinux active? check in the command line the result of `sestatus`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running a MS SQL server?  As far as I am aware, the XAMPP packages comes with a MySQL server.  Try and use `mysqli_connect()` with the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you used mssql_connect?

Btw, I would use the [PHP driver](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx) offered by Microsoft to allow PHP to connect Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

After wiresharking the network connection, I find that PHP is trying to connect to the SQL Server on port 4000 instead of 1433.